# Uncaught TypeError: manager.push(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, local-storage

im working on a todo list manager project. it was all working fine until I tried adjusting it to work with local storage
this is my code below - it seems like every function suddenly is not recognized and i cant tell why.

https://jsfiddle.net/3sjhkt0m/

manager is an set to local storage like this :

```
manager = new TaskManager();
manager.addTask("Portfolio project");
localStorage.setItem("userManager", JSON.stringify(manager));
```

TaskManager creates an array of the type Task, all defined in a different file in the project

```
function addNewTask() {     
  alert("hello");     
  let description = (document.getElementById("description") as HTMLInputElement).value;    
  manager.push(new Task(description))       
  (document.getElementById("description") as HTMLInputElement).value = "";    
  showTasksInLists();
}
```

I was expecting the function to add a new task to the tasks array but for some reason it wont work

```
main.js:43 Uncaught TypeError: manager.push(...) is not a function
    at addNewTask (main.js:43:40)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:32:64)
```

```
index.html:49 Uncaught ReferenceError: updateDescription is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:49:39)
```

```
2main.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: manager.findIndex is not a function
    at completeTask (main.js:22:33)
```

Comment: First you use manager as a class, with an addTask function. Later you try to push to it like it’s an array. You also try to serialize it to JSON, the deserialization of which won’t be a Manager but am object. I’d guess whatever the Manager class is don’t have a “push” method or you’re using it after deserializing. If you’re trying to save the tasks you should serialized only the tasks, and use whatever Manager provided to rehydrate those tasks.

Comment: im still learning the topic so im having a difficult time understanding it to the fullest... how can i make sure i serialized only the tasks?

Comment: @luna Dave means the `manager` is most probably not an array (hence it does have push function/findIndex function). You should parse (deserialize) it, something along the lines of `let manager = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userManager"));`

Comment: We don't know what a `TaskManager` is. If it's some sort of class that maintains a task list simply serializing it to JSON will not do what you want. We have no way of knowing how to use a `TaskManager` to get a list of tasks that could be put in local storage. In the fiddle there's a bunch of functions that imply a `TaskManager` is an array of tasks *(which is odd naming; `TaskManager` implies it actually **does** something)*. Because the fiddle is incomplete it's very difficult to help.

Comment: I'd also note that the fiddle has nothing referring to a `TaskManager`; it appears in the fiddle the "task manager" is expected to be an array of tasks *(typically named `tasks`)*. The question on SO should contain enough information to answer the question; the fiddle is non-functional as-is and appears to be different anyway.

Comment: My bad , i updated the fiddle with the classes of "Task" and "Task manager. I guess the problem is that when I retrieve the array from local storage it doesnt have the 'TaskManager" Class anymore. I think the solution is assigning the "TaskManager" class after I get it from the local storage but I wasnt able to do so. let me know what you think :)